# EGit push operation giving error: "Error occurred during unpacking the remote end"

Tags: eclipse, git, repository, egit

Error occurred during unpacking the remote end

Steps, which I followed:
On system A (remote):

1. Installed EGit
2. Create a project
3. Share that project
4. Create repository
5. Add and commit that project to repository
6. (share the repository folder)

On system B (local):

1. Install EGit
2. Import project (by cloning remote repository)
3. select clone (not add)
4. give the path of remote repository like 192.168.10.28\Git\repo
5. check the branch
6. give destination path(local)
7. follow simple steps and import the project
8. Modify the code
9. commit it to local repository
10. Now go to repository view and push the local repository content to the remote 1
11. ERROR window pops up saying

**"Can't connect to any repository: \192.168.100.28\Git\repo (An internal Exception occurred during push: \192.168.100.28\Git\repo: Pipe closed)"**

Answer (score 6):

The only "pipe closed" error on Egit is mentioned in [bug 314107](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=314107) and isn't related to your case.

The only suspicious element in your scenario is the address of your remote repo.
With the file protocol, I would specify:

```
file:///192.168.100.28/Git/repo.git
```

---

As the [OP Abhay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111740/abhay) comments, the **destination folder was write protected**, which was enough to trigger that error message.

Comment: Thanks buddy, actually mistake was silly. Destination folder was write protected. Now I gave the permission and its working well.

Comment: @Abhay: excellent. I have included that root cause in my answer.

Comment: I had the same "pipe closed" issue because of I ran out of space on my disk. Your hint gave me the right idea.

Answer (score 6):

This issue is not specific to Egit. It occurs when git cannot write to the destination folder on the remote system. This could be, as noted in another answer, that the folder did not have the correct permissions. It could also be for other reasons, such as in my case where the file system had reached full capacity.