# Maven jgitflow plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, hudson, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I don't know if any of you do use the maven plugin jgitflow.
when running

```
clean jgitflow:release-start jgitflow:release-finish
```

on hudson, I get the following error:

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>       execute goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-start 
>       (default-cli) on project test-git-release: Execution default-cli of goal 
>       external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-start 
>       failed: String index out of range: -6

My pom.xml looks as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
 <groupid>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupid>
 <artifactid>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactid>
 <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
  <configuration>
   <enablesshagent>true</enablesshagent>
   <defaultoriginurl>URL</defaultoriginurl> 
   <autoversionsubmodules>true</autoversionsubmodules>  
   <nodeploy>true</nodeploy>    
   <pushreleases>true</pushreleases>
    <flowinitcontext>
     <versiontagprefix>V_</versiontagprefix>
    </flowinitcontext>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

On my local machine I am able to run this command successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/maven-jgitflow-users/pchPs1JVHig) is a known bug: [official bug report](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/MJF-249), for the same version you mentioned and same behavior (working fine locally but same exception on Jenkins/Hudson).

Note that the linked bug report above provides a workaround maybe worth to try:

> The workaround is in Jenkins:
>   Additional Behaviours
>   => checkout to specific local branch

---

**Update**
According to the comments exchanged, proposed solutions and effective resolutions, here is the historical log for future helps:

- Following the suggested workaround above and setting the local branch to checkout from origin/develop, the following error was encountered:
  `error occurred during unpacking on the remote end: unpack-objects abnormal exit`
- Such an error was actually due to permissions on the concerned folder, as also suggested by other SO threads, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187528/git-configuration-with-eclipse-not-able-to-push-code-from-eclipse-to-remote-git) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898042/egit-push-operation-giving-error-error-occurred-during-unpacking-the-remote-en). However changing the permissions afterwards did not help.
- The issue was finally solved by creating the .git repository on the server itself. Doing so gave the group of the folder the same permissions as the owner.

Comment: After setting the local branch to checkout from as 'origin/develop' I get the following error:  `error occurred during unpacking on the remote end: unpack-objects abnormal exit`

Comment: @edmond sounds like directory permissions configuration, can you check that?

Comment: Upon setting the permissions I am now getting "short read of block" as error.

Comment: Hi @A. Di Matteo. how should the permissions configuration look like? Thanks

Comment: @edmond permissions about the read/write on the concerned folders, did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187528/git-configuration-with-eclipse-not-able-to-push-code-from-eclipse-to-remote-git) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898042/egit-push-operation-giving-error-error-occurred-during-unpacking-the-remote-en) threads?

Comment: Hi @A. Di Matteo. The problem was really the permissions. I had created the git project on my local machine and copied it on the server with scp. Even changing the permissions afterwareds did not help. To solve the issue, I created the .git repository on the server itself. Doing so gave the group of the folder the same permissions as the owner.

Comment: @edmon great, what do you prefer? I update the answer accordingly with the history of these comments or you prefer to post another answer? So that the question doesn't remain unanswered

Comment: I prefer the first option. I mean updating the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A little timesaver for all the folks working with GitLab and experiencing this problem:

GitLab's Runner works on a DETACHED HEAD, which causes JGitFlow's search for GIT refs to fail, resulting in exactly this error.

The solution is as it is for Jenkins: before performing the JGitFlow operation, make a checkout. For GitLab you can do this by adding a git checkout in the /script part of the respective pipeline your gitlab-ci.yml, for example:

```
sample-pipeline:
   stage: release
   script: 
   -git checkout -B master
   -mvn --batch-mode jgitflow:release-start jgitflow:release-finish
```

Since JGitFlow automatically checks out the develop branch and does its magic from there, you can always check out the master beforehand, as it has no effect at all; its just important that its not a DETACHED HEAD when GitLab starts its search for refs.